# How to access the DOM element of a third party component that doesn't forward ref

Tags: reactjs, devextreme, react-functional-component, react-beautiful-dnd

I am working with a third-party component which doesn't [forward the ref to its DOM component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) and unfortunately, I need to get a ref to its DOM element in my code.

The code below obviously fails:

```
const ThirdPartyComponent = (props) => {
  return <div>I'm a third party component</div>;
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return <ThirdPartyComponent ref={ref} />;
};
```

> "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref
> will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?"

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-noether-vidym?file=/src/App.tsx) here.

Is there anyway to get a ref to the DOM element inside the third party component? I'm aware of the [deprecated findDOMNode API](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#warning-about-deprecated-finddomnode-usage). I'm not too keen on it, but even though, I did not manage to make it work.

Note: I know that what I'm asking for is not considered as good practice. The reason I'm doing this is to  have [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) work with [DevExtreme's Reactive Grid](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive). `Draggable` components expects a ref to the draggable elements (the `<tr>`s here, which I don't have). Just trying to simplify the question.

Comment: Try using a wrapper component

Comment: That was my initial workaround. But in the actual use case, the element is a TR, and TRs can't be wrapped in another element 